# How to find the day of a Date

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I want to find the day of the week of a particular date in Qt.
e.g.: 1/05/2010 is Sunday.

Is it possible to find the weekday using date?

Answer (score 16):

```
QDate date;
date.setDate(2010,5,1);
int day = date.dayOfWeek();
QString weekDay = QDate::longDayName(day);
```

This isn't tested. But hope it will work. Check it out and let know.

Answer (score 2):

int QDate::dayOfWeek () const

Returns the weekday (1 to 7) for this date.

For example,

```
QDate date;
date.setDate(2010, 5, 1);

switch (date.dayOfWeek()) {
 case 1:
  // Monday
  break;
 // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the QDate class and the dayOfWeek function.

> int QDate::dayOfWeek () const
>
> Returns the weekday (1 to 7) for this date.